# How to clone/open GitHub Gist in PyCharm IDE?

Tags: github, pycharm, git-clone

In PyCharm IDE I see only repos to open from VCS, but I want to open Gist! Is it possible in some decent way (not by copy-paste)?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer by myself:

1. Open Gist at GitHub;
2. Choose Clone via HTTPS;
3. Copy the link to the Gist;
4. In PyCharm, "get from version control", paste the link to Repository URL.